# How to use optional attributes in Spring Data / Webflux

Tags: spring-data, spring-webflux

I´m trying to work with joins in Spring-Webflux. I have two tables, `comments` and `votes`.
My Comment Entity has an attribute named score, which is the calculated number of votes.
The problem is this score isn´t a field inside the database, but at the moment a transient marked field in the Comment Object which is calculated by my application with bad performance.

My goal is to calculate this with a Join and not in my Application.
My Problem is that Spring doesn´t map the score field because of the transient annotation, which is needed because other Operations (patch or update) doesn´t provide this score field.

My Repository looks like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Comment, UUID> {

    @Query("SELECT C.*, COALESCE(SUM(v.vote), 0) as score FROM comment c LEFT JOIN vote v ON c.id = v.comment_id WHERE c.room_id = $1 GROUP BY c.id")
    Flux<Comment> findByRoomIdWithScore(UUID roomId);

    Flux<Comment> findByRoomId(UUID roomId);
    @Transactional
    Flux<Void> deleteByRoomId(UUID roomId);
}
```

and my Comment Object is this:

```java
@Table
public class Comment implements Persistable<UUID> {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private UUID roomId;
    private UUID creatorId;
    private String body;
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private boolean read;
    private boolean favorite;
    private int correct;
    private boolean ack;
    @Transient
    private int score;
    private String tag;
    private String answer;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id == null;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UUID getRoomId() {
        return roomId;
    }

    public void setRoomId(UUID roomId) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }

    public UUID getCreatorId() {
        return creatorId;
    }

    public void setCreatorId(UUID creatorId) {
        this.creatorId = creatorId;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public boolean isRead() {
        return read;
    }

    public void setRead(boolean read) {
        this.read = read;
    }

    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return favorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public int getCorrect() {
        return correct;
    }

    public void setCorrect(int correct) {
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    public boolean isAck() {
        return ack;
    }

    public void setAck(boolean ack) {
        this.ack = ack;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Comment{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", roomId='" + roomId + '\'' +
                ", creatorId='" + creatorId + '\'' +
                ", body='" + body + '\'' +
                ", timestamp=" + timestamp +
                ", read=" + read +
                ", favorite=" + favorite +
                ", correct=" + correct +
                ", ack=" + ack +
                ", score=" + score +
                ", tag=" + tag +
                ", answer=" + answer +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I´ve already tried to make another Comment class without the transient annotation, but that doesn´t work because of the used Repository i guess: `reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property must not be null!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create another Class which extends Comment with the non transient score attribute. This could be casted back into a comment and the score is set